# How do I find which port number .Net Remoting Allocates?

Tags: .net, remoting, port

If I create a TcpChannel using port zero i.e. allowing .Net Remoting to allocate an available port, is there anyway to then determine which port number has been allocated?

I know that I can specify the port number when creating the channel, however I don't want to do this as I want to run multiple instances of the listening application on the same Citrix server - each instance listening on a different port.

Ideally I don't want to have to go to the trouble of reserving a bunch of ports and then keeping track of which ones have been allocated.  I'd just like to let the port be allocated automatically - but then I need to be able to know which port number has been allocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was as follows:

- Use the following code to identify an unused port for each instance of the client application:

  ```
  IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

  using (Socket socket = new Socket(
               AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
               SocketType.Stream, 
               ProtocolType.Tcp))
  {
      socket.Bind(endPoint);
      IPEndPoint local = (IPEndPoint)socket.LocalEndPoint;
      return local.Port;
  }
  ```
- Store the unused port number in the client application.
- Pass the stored port number to the host application via a command line parameter for use when setting up the TcpChannel and calling Activator.GetObject.
- Use the stored port number in the client application in the URL passed to Activator.GetObject.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know much about this, but browsing at MSDN it states that post zero usage returns a `TcpServerChannel`, and a `TcpServerChannel` has a `GetChannelUri()` method; does that include the port number? (you might need to parse, via `new Uri(s).Port`).

Again, complete guess-work. If not, just say ;-p

*edit by AakashM to add* This is the correct approach. Following

```
var channel = new TcpChannel(0);
```

the dynamically-allocated post of the contained server channel can be retrieved with

```
var channelData = (ChannelDataStore)channel.ChannelData;
var port = new System.Uri(channelData.ChannelUris[0]).Port;
```

The ugly cast is necessary because the `TcpChannel.ChannelData` property is typed as `object`...

Comment: Looking at the sourcecode for the implementation of TcpServerChannel in Mono, I think you're right. The url is in the form tcp://host:port (see
http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mcs/class/System.Runtime.Remoting/System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp/TcpServerChannel.cs?annotate=HEAD#l182 )

Comment: Well in theory that would have worked - except that I was using a TcpChannel as opposed to a TcpServerChannel.  I've ended up posting an answer with my solution.

Comment: In the other answer I believe you leave a time period that the port can be taken away, so this is superior for my needs, thanks!